# Is time-series filtering available within ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, filter, time-series

I have a data frame in R with multiple time-series. The data frame consists of 3 columns of data: test, timeHr, and range.

The test column specifies the actual name of the test carried out, and the range gives a numeric value specific to a particular hour (denoted by timeHr).

What I would like to do, is if a particular time-series exceeds an upper and/or a lower bound at any timepoint timeHr, then it will be omitted from the final ggplot.

Here is some sample code, showing only 2 time series:

```
library(ggplot2)
test <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B")
timeHr <- 1:5
range <- c(0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.9, 1.1, 0.5)
mdata <- data.frame(test, timeHr, range)
mdata
str(mdata)
g <- ggplot(mdata, aes(x = timeHr, y = range, color = test))
g + geom_line() + ylim(0, 1.5)
```

This shows 2 time-series A and B.

If I wish to only include time-series where range is <= 1, what code could I use within ggplot?

I have tried the following:

```
g <- ggplot(mdata[mdata$range <= 1, ], aes(x = timeHr, y = range, color = test))
g + geom_line() + ylim(0, 1.5)
```

but all that does is that it deletes the single B timepoint at (timeHr = 4, range = 1.1). The B test time series is still shown, but in a distorted way.

Can **ggplot** handle filtering of timeseries, so that test B would be dropped from the plot if I want to show only those time series which remain within a specific range throughout the entire timeHr universe?

Thanks!

Comment: mdata %>% dplyr::filter(range <= 1 & test=="A") %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = timeHr, y = range, color = test)) + geom_line() + ylim(0, 1.5)

Comment: Hi Dr Flow, the code you suggested doesn't seem to work. I still see a distorted B time series, rather than just A on its own. I assume I only need to load dplyr and ggplot2 packages?

Comment: I don't want to specify test=="A" in the code, because I will have many time-series, and I want the code to do the hard labour of checking which time-series actually satisfy the range value conditions.

Comment: not sure what u mean, this may work: mdata[which(mdata$range <= .5), names(mdata) %in% c("test" ,"timeHr","range")]. if not maybe you need an if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to do the filtering inline you can use `dplyr`.  This uses `group_by` to consider each test as a group, then `filter` such that `all` values of `range` are <=1.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
    mdata %>% 
      group_by(test) %>% 
      filter(all(range <= 1)) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = timeHr, y = range, color = test)) +
      geom_line() + ylim(0, 1.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Greg, that's exactly the functionality I was looking for. I was hoping it could be handled directly in ggplot2, but using dplyr will not be too difficult, now you have shown me how. Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help.  `ggplot` and `dplyr` are closely connected and `ggplot` functionality is often unlocked by `dplyr`.  They're both made by the same person (Hadley Wickham) so it's no accident.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then I will suggest that you make another data frame, which is actually the subset of `mdata` with the condition that range be <=1, And then try to make the gig-lot upon that data. Try the following codes:

```
m2data <- subset(mdata, range<=1)
str(m2data)
g <- ggplot(m2data, aes(x = timeHr, y = range, color = test))
g + geom_line() + ylim(0, 1.5)
```

Comment: Hi Sayantan4796, subsetting mdata to m2data, only deletes a single timepoint from test B. I want the whole of test B to be dropped if it exceeds a range value.

Comment: If `m2data <- subset(mdata, range<=1)` does not work, then try

`m2data <- subset(mdata, c(range<1 & range =1))`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. I still get a distorted B test time-series plotted, rather than completely omitted.

Comment: That means you dont want to continue plotting B after it crosses the 1.0 mark

Comment: No, I don't want B in its entirety plotted at all if it is ever > 1